# New classes files appear outside of project folder in Xcode

Tags: xcode

When I go to create a new objective-C class in Xcode I first select which group I want it to be in.  So for example, I'm in mainViewController/detail/cells/  (meaning I have that highlighted in the project navigator).  I create the class and choose the right folder in my directory to add it when Xcode prompts me.  When I hit OK the files (.h,.m) appear at the top of the project navigator outside of the blue project folder.  Than I have to move them to the group I intended them to be in and the dialog prompt pops up asking me whether I want to copy them.  I choose no as the files already exist in my folder.  This makes the files red (missing reference) and I have to point them back to the files in the folder.  The net result of this is that my class files get screwed up somehow and nothing autocompletes.  What is going on here?

Comment: When you're choosing the real directory for the generated files, there should be a "group" dropdown near the bottom of the modal sheet - does selecting a group from there work as expected?